# JQUERY: this closest classname fadeOut is fading multiple elements

Tags: jquery

The following is the output html of a php loop.

```
<div class="item clearfix" style="cursor: default;">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="/social/user.php?user=user1">
            <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0edee6b101a7aaa324ffd0dfb2f00dc?d=retro&amp;s=32" width="32">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
        <a href="/social/user.php?user=user1" class="name">
            User1
        </a>
        <span style="left:40%">Friend Request</span>
        <span style="left:80%">
            <a href="#" class="accept_friend" title="accept_friend">
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: xx-large; color: green;"></i>
            </a>
        </span>

        <span style="left:88%">
            <a href="#" class="deny_friend" title="deny_friend">
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: xx-large; color: #CB2C1A;"></i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item clearfix" style="cursor: default;">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="/social/user.php?user=user2">
            <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0edee6b101a7aaa324ffd0dfb2f00dc?d=retro&amp;s=32" width="32">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
        <a href="/social/user.php?user=user2" class="name">
            User2
        </a>
        <span style="left:40%">Friend Request</span>
        <span style="left:80%">
            <a href="#" class="accept_friend" title="accept_friend">
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: xx-large; color: green;"></i>
            </a>
        </span>

        <span style="left:88%">
            <a href="#" class="deny_friend" title="deny_friend">
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: xx-large; color: #CB2C1A;"></i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This next bit is my jquery script.

```
$(document).on("click", "a.accept_friend", function() { 
    var removeit = $(this).closest(':has(.item)').find('.item').fadeOut();
    return removeit;
});
```

for some reason when either class="accept_friend" is clicked, both class="item" 's are being removed instead of just the .closest(':has(.item)') to the clicked event.

Obviously for an end result, when class="accept_friend" is clicked I only want the container class="item" of the clicked element to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest(':has(.item)')` finds element that has child elements with class item in it, which is body tag.and `.find('.item')` on body element select all the elements that are `.item`. which is 2 in current case.

You need to traverse to item element and fade it out:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.accept_friend", function() { 
  var removeit = $(this).closest('.item').fadeOut();
  return removeit;
});
```

Comment: This is SUCH a helpful answer! That explains a LOT

Comment: @Bruce: Glad it helps :)